# Search all world with elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I don't figure out how to do multi world query.

I follow [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/2.x/_closer_is_better.html) guide, but if is not full match , i get no results.

for this query :

```
"query": {
    "match" : {
        "name" : "GOODYEAR TIRE"
    }
}
```

i get:

```
"hits": {
"total": 2,
"max_score": 10.46396,
"hits": [
{
"_index": "holdings1",
"_type": "searchentity",
"_id": "80809219-88a0-49bc-96b6-183db8a7d056",
"_score": 10.46396,
"_source": {
"guid": "80809219-88a0-49bc-96b6-183db8a7d056",
...
"name": "GOODYEAR TIRE",
"issuer": "GOODYEAR TIRE & RUBBER CO (GT)",
...
}
}
```

But for this i got nothing :

```
"query": {
    "match" : {
        "issuer" : "GOODYEAR TIRE"
    }
}
```

mapping:

```
"searchentity": {
                "properties": {
                      .....
                    "issuer": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "custom"
                    },
                    "name": {
                        "type": "text",
                        "analyzer": "custom"
                    }
                     ......
                }
            }
```

analyzers(c#):

```
        .Settings(s => s.NumberOfReplicas(1).NumberOfShards(1).Analysis(a => a.Analyzers(an => an.Custom("custom", ca => ca
                        .Tokenizer("keyword")
                        .CharFilters("remove-specials")
                        .Filters("lowercase")
                    )).CharFilters(charFilters => charFilters.PatternReplace("remove-specials", p => p.Pattern("[^0-9a-zA-Z\u0590-\u05fe\x20]+")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting result as  `GOODYEAR TIRE & RUBBER CO (GT)` doesn't contain `GOODYEAR RUBBER` as a phrase.

Phrase means it all the words must be exactly the same and in order.

You should try the [match_query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) and it would return the results.

Let me know if you face any issue constructing the match query.

Comment: can u share your query and mapping of your index?

Comment: @yantrab, can you proivide the o/p of mapping api https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-mapping.html

Comment: @yantrab , can you change `Tokenizer("keyword")` to Tokenizer("standard") and try again? You need to update the mapping and index the document again and then test.

Comment: @yantrab , glad it heped.